# Unable to change session variable through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I have the message-block in the header of my site. When a user clicks "close msg", the message should disapear and can't be seen during current user session.
So I decided to use jQuery Ajax:

```
$('#lang-msg .close').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:"remlmsg.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:"id=2,myajaxquery=true ",
        success:function(html){
            console.log(html);
            $('#lang-msg').fadeOut(300,function() {
                $(this).remove();
            })
        }
    })
})
```

And in **remlmsg.php** I have only code, which defines new session variable:

```
    $_SESSION['langmsg'] = 'hide';
    echo $_SESSION['langmsg'];
```

In the header.php file I check if **$_SESSION['langmsg']** is undefined.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['langmsg'])) {         
    if ($sLanguage == 'ru') {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                $( function() {
                    showLangMessage("en");  
                })
            </script>';
    }
}
```

And it says always true! But when I print request data in ajax function it displays 'hide'.
Explain to me, please, where I did mistake.

P.S.
Tested on local server (latest WAMP)

Comment: are you using session_start at the top of the file?

Comment: I have it in header.php file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `session_start()` declared first. Otherwise you'll only edit a local variable that isn't stored anywhere.

Comment: I have session_start() in header.php - so session declares always before ajax request.

Comment: Putting session_start() in every file where I access or set session variables helped me out.

Comment: onlydimon: maybe you have included it in the file that has the script which is making the ajax call, but not in the server-side script that is processing the request.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem you're having is that ajax calls will have a different session id, which has to do with the headers sent/received by both sides.

Try generating some javascript with PHP like:

```
var phpSessionId='<?=session_id()?>';
```

then in your remlmsg.php add this to the very top:

```
if(isset($_POST['session-id'])) session_id($_POST['session-id']);
session_start();
```

Finally in your ajax call use:

```
data:"id=2,myajaxquery=true,session-id=" + phpSessionId,
```

That should solve your problem.